# How can I specify sql sort order in sql query

Tags: sql

I have the follow SQL query statement:

```
SELECT subject, sender_list, date, uid
FROM messages
WHERE folder_id = 3
```

Can you please tell how can I specify query sort order?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's actually quite easy. Here's an example to sort your query by the "subject":

```
SELECT subject, sender_list, date, uid
  FROM messages
 WHERE folder_id = 3
 ORDER BY subject ASC
```

This will order your list A-Z. If you want to order your list Z-A then use:

```
ORDER BY subject DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "ORDER BY"

For more information check out [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
SELECT subject, sender_list, date, uid
  FROM messages
 WHERE folder_id = 3
 ORDER BY subject ASC
```

but i wouldn't mind taking off the 'asc' at the end being that  ASC is true by default.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp